# Tomato Router: Configure LAN4 to obtain IP from ISP

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt, tomato

I would like to achieve a configuration of my network where a server/PC/set-top-box connected to LAN4 port obtain IP from ISP, and it is visible on ISP's network. Thank you for any suggestions.

I managed to separate both LAN4 and WAN port in one VLAN but I am still missing some configuration steps to make it fully work. For better explanation, check linked question below. *I am currently running Tomato firmware on Linksys E3200, I do not mind to change it to DD-WRT or other firmware if the configuration is simpler with this firmware.*

Desired scheme from the Question [Tomato: routing WAN traffic to local port](https://superuser.com/questions/920863/tomato-routing-wan-traffic-to-local-port/)
:

```
                            Internet
                            WAN IP: 11.11.11.11
                                |
            Server              |
            WAN IP: 11.11.11.22 |
                        |       |
Computer                |       |
local IP: 192.168.2     |       |
    |                   |       |
    |                   |       |
+------+------+------+------+-----+
| LAN1 | LAN2 | LAN3 | LAN4 | WAN | < physical ports
|                    |            |
| <----- VLAN 1 ---->| <- VLAN2 ->| < VLANs
| 192.168.1.x range  | WAN range  |
|                    |            |
|           <=== NAT ===>         |
+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: It doesn't look like any special configuration is needed (aside from setting up VLANs as depicted)... as long as the router's switch hardware supports it. What configuration do you have currently?

Comment: Yes, exactly I have default Tomato configuration besides some basic wifi configuration and already mentioned VLAN settings.